# How to include html when searching with "inspect elements"?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

Ok, this seems simple but I've been scratching my head over this.

When I go to "inspect elements", and I see this (for example):

```
    <div class="topbar">
```

I can use search to find "topbar", but not the whole thing (with the ">").
Is there some simple way to search for all text, including the html part, using google chrome's devtools?

Comment: If you really want all the text and html then why not click on **View page source** and then search for whatever you want.

Comment: @ReubenSanders Did u go through the question before posting the comment? Your link has little relation with the question here.

Comment: @ReubenSanders view page source doesn't have the dynamic things being loaded in (what I'm looking for isn't in the page source).

Comment: @CRAKC The questions are asking the same thing, although the one I linked doesn't actually formulate a question.

Comment: @grasshopper Which elements are you speaking of specifically that are  not there in the source? Can you upload a screenshot and make the question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to try and work around this is to use the selector, in this case `.topbar` when searching. It appears that currently the string selection only searches content text, not the DOM structure.

If you want to see if the search can get updated we always welcome [new bug reports](http://crbug.com/new). The DevTools group doesn't mind feature requests through this system. Please have "DevTools" in the title so it is easy for any triager to know where to send it.

Comment: I see, it doesn't search structure at the moment. It seems like such a simple thing that an existing tool must already accomplish this! Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as it seems. This is a DOM structure view, so it isn't exactly plaintext searching what is shown directly. It appears to conduct queries against the underlying DOM then highlights the results. Once you start adding spaces and brackets in, the queries break down so nothing is shown, or the incorrect things.